# Show configurable products on product info page

Tags: product, configurable-product, up-sells, related-products

I am trying to show configurable products in the upsell block on the product info page.
i have already "linked" the products, cleared cache and reindexed data. but still not showing up.

Comment: Are they showing up on your other pages?

Comment: check their status,visibility,stock status, assigned to website if multiple

Comment: no they are not showing up...
visibility, stock  and status, its ok....
if i set simple products they show... but configurables dont.... =(

Comment: if your configurable products are not showing anywhere in the frontend then you have a problem with the product config, as mentioned above.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/94306/243