# Magento does not display all imported products within the categories

Tags: product-list, stock, importexport, products-management

I have set up the categories and imported the products CSV into Magento, which all worked fine. Each category is display the correct amount of products within the backend. However on the frontend, Magento does not display all of the products in the categories, only the first few. All products are set to be in stock and all have a quantity of at least 1.

[image: Block Category Screenshot]

As you can see the category 'Bloch' has 2233 products. However on the frontend, Magento is only display 6. Screenshot below.

[image: Magento Frontend Screenshot]

I have re-indexed the site multiple times as well making sure all products are in stock and visible.

Can anyone help as to why this might be happening?

Answer (score 4):

Possible causes for products that do not appear on the frontend (I include those that you already ruled out for sake of completeness):

- the products' "visibility" attribute might be set to "Not visible individually" or "Search" instead of "Catalog" or "Catalog/Search"
- the products' "status" attribute might be set to "Disabled"
- the products' "stock" might be set to "Out of stock". Note that this setting is independent from the stock qty!
- if you have configurable products, make sure that the simple products are enabled and in stock as well
- any of these settings might have been overridden in the store scope (switch from "Default" in the top left dropdown)
- the indexes are not up to date
- the cache is not up to date

Comment: _if you have configurable products, make sure that the simple products are enabled and in stock as well_ was a problem in my case, on just created website scope.